# UITextFieldDelegate vs UITextField control events

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicontrol, uitextfielddelegate

If I want to handle changes to a UITextField, such as the user typing in it; it seems like this can be done either by assigning a delegate to that text field, and then having the delegate implement shouldChangeCharactersInRange, or by adding a target to the textField, and handling the UIControlEventEditingChanged event.

Aside from the fact that with the delegate method, you can return NO and therefor stop the user from making the edit, is there any difference between these 2 things?

Same question for handling the beginning of editing or the ending of editing. It could be done either with the appropriate delegate methods or with the appropriate events. What is the textField delegate actually for if the control events can do the necessary work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right; you can essentially do the same thing via both, but UIControl is lower level and lets you siphon off each particular UIEvent to different targets via `[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]` where as there is only a single delegate.

I would also say that the [UITextField delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) is simply there as a more convenient, higher level alternative to UIControl/UIEvent as a way to manage the behaviour of a UITextField.

The most common delegate pattern is UITableView DataSource and Delegate and I would say that using the UITextField delegate protocol is quite similar and therefore looks far more straight forward with more defined intentions than handing the messages from UIControl directly.

Answer (score 9):

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called before a change occurs, and gives you opportunity to 'cancel' the change.  `UIControlEventEditingChanged` is called after the change occurred.

You can determine the resulting value of the textField in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, but you have to manually apply the replacementString to the existing text, using the supplied range.  (via `NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`).  If you want to know the resulting text, it's easier and more efficient to use `UIControlEventEditingChanged`.

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is often used to implement validation checking of input - that is, you can filter characters/pasted text as it is entered.  If a field is for phone numbers, for example, you can return `FALSE` if the user types a non numeric character, or attempts to paste in text that isn't numeric.

You might find a case where you can reuse code for multiple controls if you can stick with the `UIControlEvent-methods.`

Answer (score 6):

One key difference I've found between the two approaches posed in the original question is that the delegate `"shouldChangeCharactersInRange"` gets called **BEFORE** the value in the `UITextField` changes.  The target for `UIControlEventEditingChanged` gets called **AFTER** the value in the `UITextField` changes.

In the case that you're using these events to make sure (for example) that all fields in a dialog are completely filled in before enabling a "Done" button, the target approach may work better for you.  It did for me.

Answer (score 1):

The delegation approach is the way to homogenize `UITextField` and `UITextView` behavior.

`UITextView` does not have control events. In contrast, `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextviewDelegate` provide parallel methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` passes the same `NSRange` for insertion and deletion of text. You append a space and then delete it, and the parameters from `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` are indistinguishable from duplication of the text.

So `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` actually cannot predict the resulting text.